# What is the taste of an unripened date or plum?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

What do you call that sensation that you feel when you eat raw diospyros? IO don’t know the actual name. It also happens when you try to eat banana peel and you get that sensation in your mouth. What’s that called?

It's like when you taste raw courgettes, or sometimes from unripened grape skin.
The reason I ask is because I’ve no idea what this sensation is called in English, because I’ve never heard of native English speakers talk about it.

Answer (score 9):

I believe the word you are looking for is [astringent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astringent).

Comment: According to your link, the word is actually _astringency_: "Astringency is also the dry, puckering mouthfeel caused by tannins"

Comment: @oerkelens, yes, _astringency_ is then noun, _astringent_ is the adjective.

Answer (score 7):

What you describe seems to be what wine-tasters know as [*tannin*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tannin), the taste of which may be described as [*tannic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tannic).

The specific effect is described in tea as [*astringency*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/astringency):

> Tannins give tea astringency, colour, and some flavour.

Comment: An awful lot of people would simply use ***bitter***, but I agree ***astringent, tannic*** are a bit more "specific". Plus people will often use variations on ***mouth-puckering***.

Comment: But bitter is an actual taste sensation, whereas astringency is something different. We tend to be careless in describing tastes though (like sweet and sour being opposites...), and, yes, this effect _is_ indeed often called bitterness.

Comment: The difference between ***bitter*** and ***astringent*** is subjective even if we suppose there are archetypal substances which could be said to "objectively" generate such taste sensations in a "non-overlapping" way. You may be quite convinced that *bitter is an actual taste sensation, whereas astringency is something different*, but I honestly doubt whatever distinction you intend would be universally (or even, *generally*), recognised by others. People are usually pretty hopeless at describing tastes, in my experience.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: hopeless as they may be, but sweet, sour, bitter and salt are mostly happening on the tongue. None of them makes your gums literally stick to your teeth in the way astringency does. So apart from taste, there is a clear physical difference in this case. Which of course does not keep people from calling that "hey my gums are like glued sandpaper against my teeth" - feeling a bitter _taste_.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Bitter and astringent are distinct, just like salty and sweet are distinct. People may not know how to describe them, but that doesn't mean that the difference is subjective.

Comment: @Jefromi: OED's only non-obsolete definitions for adjectival ***astringent*** are *1. Having power to draw together or contract the soft organic tissues; binding, constrictive, styptic,* leading to *2. fig. Severe, austere, stern.* You may think the word distinguishes some precise quality, but it's not easy to identify, and there won't be any genuine consensus. Most people would say *astringent = mouth-puckering*, for example, but they'd not normally use it for, say, *lemon juice* (because that encourages salivation, and people think of astringent as "drying").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had no idea the OED's definitions didn't cover the common usage of "astringent" in a culinary context. But again, regardless of the definitions have managed to give to the terms, and regardless of how many people are aware of the differences, there are distinct physical sensations referred to by astringent and bitter. I'm not claiming that no one would call it "bitter" (plenty of people would) but to say that the difference is subjective is misleading. It's people's vocabulary and awareness that keep them from distinguishing, not a lack of an objective difference.

Comment: @Jefromi You all may be interested to know that ["astringent" is one of the six basic tastes in the Tamil language.](http://ta.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%B1%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%9A%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%B5%E0%AF%88) In traditional Tamil culture, a feast is not considered complete unless it includes all six basic tastes.